# C++: Issues with Circular Buffer

Tags: c++

I'm having some trouble writing a circular buffer in C++. Here is my code base at the moment:

circ_buf.h:

```
#ifndef __CIRC_BUF_H__
#define __CIRC_BUF_H__


#define MAX_DATA (25)  // Arbitrary size limit

// The Circular Buffer itself
struct circ_buf {
    int s;               // Index of oldest reading
    int e;               // Index of most recent reading
    int data[MAX_DATA];  // The data
};

/*** Function Declarations ***/
void empty(circ_buf*);
bool is_empty(circ_buf*);
bool is_full(circ_buf*);
void read(circ_buf*, int);
int overwrite(circ_buf*);


#endif  // __CIRC_BUF_H__
```

circ_buf.cpp:

```
#include "circ_buf.h"


/*** Function Definitions ***/

// Empty the buffer
void empty(circ_buf* cb) {
    cb->s = 0; cb->e = 0;
}

// Is the buffer empty?
bool is_empty(circ_buf* cb) {
    // By common convention, if the start index is equal to the end
    // index, our buffer is considered empty.
    return cb->s == cb->e;
}

// Is the buffer full?
bool is_full(circ_buf* cb) {
    // By common convention, if the start index is one greater than
    // the end index, our buffer is considered full.
    // REMEMBER: we still need to account for wrapping around!
    return cb->s == ((cb->e + 1) % MAX_DATA);
}

// Read data into the buffer
void read(circ_buf* cb, int k) {
    int i = cb->e;
    cb->data[i] = k;
    cb->e = (i + 1) % MAX_DATA;
}

// Overwrite data in the buffer
int overwrite(circ_buf* cb) {
    int i = cb->s;
    int k = cb->data[i];
    cb->s = (i + 1) % MAX_DATA;
}
```

circ_buf_test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "circ_buf.h"


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Our data source
    std::string file = "million_numbers.txt";
    std::fstream in(file, std::ios_base::in);

    // The buffer
    circ_buf buffer = { .s = 0, .e = 0, .data = {} };

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_DATA; ++i) {
        int k = 0; in >> k;  // Get next int from in
        read(&buffer, k);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_DATA; ++i)
        std::cout << overwrite(&buffer) << std::endl;
}
```

The main issue I'm having is getting the buffer to write integers to its array. When I compile and run the main program (circ_buf_test), it just prints the same number 25 times, instead of what I expect it to print (the numbers 1 through 25 - "million_numbers.txt" is literally just the numbers 1 through 1000000). The number is 2292656, in case this may be important.

Does anyone have an idea about what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Ever heard of *member function*?

Comment: `__CIRC_BUF_H__ ` is an identifier that is reserved for the implementation because it contains consecutive underscores. You should come up with another header guard. `CIRC_BUF_H_ ` would be OK.

Comment: @user2079303 Will do. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `overwrite(circ_buf* cb)` returns nothing (there are no `return` in it's body). So the code for printing of values can print anything (see "undefined behavior"):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < MAX_DATA; ++i)
        std::cout << overwrite(&buffer) << std::endl;
```

I expect you can find the reason of this "main issue" in the compilation log (see lines started with "Warning"). You can fix it this way:

```
int overwrite(circ_buf* cb) {
    int i = cb->s;
    int k = cb->data[i];
    cb->s = (i + 1) % MAX_DATA;
    return k;
}
```